# Split [bisection] in two

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[bisection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bisection) has 90 questions, no followers, and a very unspecific tag wiki:

> Anything related to a class of algorithms where the result is found by
>   searching either the upper or the lower half of a sorted set of items
>   and repeating this procedure recursively. Commonly used to refer to
>   the bisection method (to find a root of an equation) or to the
>   bisection search algorithm

While these things *are* all related, the zero followers seems to be good evidence that no-one is particularly interested in them at such a high level.

The questions seem to fall into the two "common uses" mentioned in the tag wiki, and none of the hypothetical others that it :

- Questions about binary search should be tagged [binary-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/binary-search).
- Questions about finding the roots of an equation should be tagged [numerical-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods). Particular root-finding algorithms are probably, in general, too specific to be a good tag here - experts on these are more likely to be found at math.SE, and detailed questions about characteristics of the algorithms (as opposed to how to implement them) are almost certainly more on topic there than here.